# Excel Userform coding structure

Tags: excel, vba

I recently started learning how to use VBA since I suddenly got put into a position where I need to know it. I've been doing research on coding and such but I feel like I'm messing up every step of the way. I was asked to create a userform where people could enter their time, date, production, task, and a comment box. I was also asked to have both the input sheet and the data sheet locked, on top of that my boss wanted the sheet itself to save when closed so when workers entered their information they wouldn't save.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lPart As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

'find first empty row in database
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1




'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.txtComment.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtComment.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Comment is required"
  End If

  'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = "" Then
  Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Date is required!"
  End If

  'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.txtTime.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Time is required"
  End If

  'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.cboProject.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cboProject.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Project is required"
  End If

  'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.cboTask.Value) = "" Then
  Me.cboTask.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Task is required"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtTime.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtCount.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cboUser.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboProject.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboTask.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtComment.Value
'  .Protect Password:="password"


'clear the data
Me.cboUser.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.txtTime.Value = ""
Me.txtCount.Value = ""
Me.cboProject.Value = ""
Me.cboTask.Value = ""
Me.txtComment.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = Format(Date, "Short Date")

MsgBox ("Work Submitted, proceed to close the form and save the workbook.")




End With
End Sub
```

Apologies in advance for how awful the code probably is, but it seemed to work just enough for what I was going, the only problem was that when I was recently testing it even if I had a message saying comment required or task required it would still paste information into the datasheet which I don't want to happen.

Comment: The check for `cboTask` uses `Exit Sub` if the control is empty but the checks on the other four controls don't use `Exit Sub` if they are empty?

Comment: I attempted to remove cboTask and the problem still persists, sorry for the redundant question

Comment: I think Barrow was trying to tell you you have to add `Exit Sub` to every `If condition`. Otherwise the code will check, you might get a message and after confirming the message the rest of the code will run. For an introduction you might have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/)